# Longitudinal design with for time-points for dependent and independent variable

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a more general question that I cannot seem to answer myself and I cannot find the answer somewhere. Linear mixed models seem to follow the format where the dependent variable is longitudinal and the independent variable is not. E.g. predicting where a change in brain volumes in associated with diagnosis. But I would like to investigate whether a change in brain volumes (over 5 time points) is associated with a change in cognitive function (over the same 5 years). So this means that both my independent and dependent variable have multiple time points. What would be the best statistical way to examine whether change in a variable is associated with change in another one?

Comment: You can still use mixed models if your independent variable is changing over time.  Or am I misunderstanding your question? Mixed models or GEE would be fine for what you are trying to study.

Comment: Yes, my question is indeed that the independent and dependent are both changing over time. I am struggling with the fact that both could have a random intercept and slope and when i look at R (lme4) I don't know how that would be taken into account...